# How to customize the JSON serialization in TRPC|zod

Tags: zod, trpc.io

Is there a way for me to show TRPC how to serialize bigint?
I'm turning BigInt into JSON by

```js
BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function() {       
  return this.toString()
}
```

And now the issue is when TRPC and Zod validate the big int it fails because its a string.

Comment: At which point are you using `zod`? Do you get `string`s from the API and want to convert them to `BigInt` on the client?

Comment: No, the issue im running into is on the server side. 
I have a `mutation` and it takes an object one of the `nested objects` has a BigInt coming from the client. Im getting an error from the createRouter() input validation. Im using the T3 trpc set up.

Answer (score 0):

I asked about this on the tRPC discord.
The answer was data transformers and using superjson

https://trpc.io/docs/v9/data-transformers